# Azure: Detach unmanaged disks, move to another storage account and reattach to same VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have 1 x OS disk and 1 x Data disk attached to *VM1*, the disks are unmanaged in storage account *mystorage*

So I know I cannot rename the storage account...

Can I instead do the following then somehow re-attach them to the Original VM again?

1. Stop *VM1*
2. In Azure Storage Explorer, for each of the disks, *Break Lease*
3. In Azure Storage Explorer, copy each disk from *mystorage* to *mynewstorage*

The only thing im not sure on how to do is re-attach them to the *VM1*

Answer (score 0):

yeah, this is a valid approach, you dont need to break the lease if you deallocate the vm (at least that is my impression).

you can use az cli to attach unmanaged disk (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/unmanaged-disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-unmanaged-disk-attach) or portal ui (https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-virtual-machines-attach-mount) or powershell

Comment: I know I can create a new VM using an existing VHD, but I was to avoid having to recreate the actual VM

Comment: I understand how to attach an existing Data Disk through the portal or Powershell, but how do I attach the OS Disk? and remove the old linkage to the storage vhd that no longer exists (This is why I thought I needed to break the lease)

Comment: you cant attach OS disk, you have to recreate

Comment: Yes as @4c74356b41 said , you can't attach OS disk . But I think you can update VM . Instead of relaunching , Stop the VM and change the os disk VHD url in existing VM Template and try a Update VM call .

Comment: highly (99.9%) doubt that @ArunKumarGR

Answer (score 0):

You could create a snapshot of the OS disk, move the snapshot to the new storage account and create the VM , that way you would keep the OS disk.